# How do extra and ultra compare?

Tags: word-comparison, adverb, preposition

The adverbs (and prepositions) *extra* and *ultra* are somewhat similar but not identical.
While I can read the two dictionary entries and get an idea what they mean, I don't feel that I fully grasp how they compare to each other?
In what sense or in which cases are they similar or interchangeable?
Are there cases when there is a clear contrast?
Is there a concise way to summarize how the two compare?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Extra* means 'on the outside' (opposite of *intra* 'on the inside'), whereas *ultra* means 'on the other side' (opposite of *citra* 'on this side').

The difference may be made clearer by looking at their composite parts. For example, *extra* is a contracted feminine ablative of the adjective *exter, extera, exterum* (i.e., *extera [via]*), which in turn is an adjectival form of the adverb *ex* 'out of'.

*Ultra* follows the same progression: *uls* 'on the other side' -> *ulter, ultera, ulterum* -> *ultera [via]* -> *ultra.*